# Why does Calendar.app offer these addresses when I type "at home" in the location field?

Tags: macos, calendar

I don't recognize any of the addresses offered by Calendar.app, when I type "at home" in the location field.   I'd like to be offered my own home address, but these look like they might be a data leak from somewhere...

[image: where do all of these addresses come from?]

I sync Calendar.app (version 8.0 (2034.9)) with Google calendar, and typically use Fantastical on iOS. My Mac OS is 10.10.5,

Comment: never tried it before - but yes; spurious results from anything with a character-match in Contacts plus a whole bunch of "helpful" suggestions from what I presume is Maps' search. Frankly, it makes it truly useless. Having said that, I think the question ought to be 'how do I stop it' rather than 'why does it happen'. 'Why' doesn't work very well for SE, as only Apple actually know the answer.

Comment: Quick fix seems to be to start typing your own name. Your home should be top hit.

Answer (score 1):

**At Home** is actually the name of a store (and so is **At Home Inn & Suites**).

If you want to set the location of an event to *your* home, either your name, or the first few digits of your street address. Your home address should bubble up to the top.

Comment: When I type "home" I get 20 hits for Homebase...

Comment: You’re right—my mistake. `Home` shows up as my top result because it’s in my **Recents**.

Comment: No worries - it is quite annoying that such a common term would first look to Contacts & local businesses... In my comment above, best I can find to work around it is start to type my own name :/

Comment: Worse yet, are that the addresses offered are not even close to me geographically, and I am logged into that Mac with location privileges turned on.